# jQuery global variable access confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, localforage

I have very specific problem, I am attempting to get the data using localforage library, assigning it to a global variable, which is a JSON.

```
$.unify.data.assets = {};
$.unify.initialization.private.intializeDefaultLayout = function() {
    localforage.getItem('assets', function($value) {
        $.unify.data.assets = $value;
        console.log($.unify.data.assets); // This shows all object in the record

    });
    console.log($.unify.data.assets); // This is empty, even on global variable assignment
};
```

I am very confused in this problem, kindly correct the required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this line is being executed in a callback

```
$.unify.data.assets = $value;
```

So there are chances the following line has been called before callback executed

```
console.log($.unify.data.assets); // This is empty, even on global variable
```

If so the `$.unify.data.assets` is not changed when you did a `console.log` so it's blank.